# Investigating slow queries in ElasticSearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

We are using elastic search version 5.4.1 in our production environments. The cluster setup is 3 data, 3 query, 3 master nodes. Of late we are observing a lot of slow queries in a particular data node and the [index][shard] present in that are just replicas.

I don't find many deleted docs or memory issues that could directly cause the slowness.

Any pointers on how to go about the investigation here would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many things are happening during one ES query. First, check the `took` field returned by ElasticSearch.

> [`took`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html) – time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to execute the search

However, the `took` field is the time that it 
took ES to process the query on its side. It doesn't include

- serializing the request into JSON on the client
- sending the request over the network
- deserializing the request from JSON on the server
- serializing the response into JSON on the server
- sending the response over the network
- deserializing the response from JSON on the client

As such, I think you should try to identify the exact step that is slow.

Reference: [Query timing: ‘took’ value and what I’m measuring](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/query-timing-took-value-and-what-im-measuring/9870)